# What's the purpose of registering window classes?

Tags: windows, winapi

What's the purpose of registering a window class via `WNDCLASSEX` and `RegisterClassEx()` when creating a window in a Windows API application?

Comment: Help to think of it in C++ terms.  Window class == C++ class, CreateWindow == new operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The separation of window attributes into CreateWindow() stuff and RegisterClass() stuff was done early on to enable the creation of uniformly-behaving windows. Dialog controls (buttons, listboxes, etc.) are a prime example - they all share a class. That means - they share a window procedure, that means - they share painting logic, input reactions, custom messages, notifications, etc.

On the app level, the most typical case when you have many windows of the same class is documents within a multiple-document interface. Sometimes people introduce app-specific controls. So the distinction serves its purpose.

Answer (score 5):

Main purpose is giving the system the right `WndProc` to call when there is something in the message queue to process.

There are some flags, but main point is the above.

Window classes correspond to types of 'widgets' on the UI:

- button
- checkbox
- scrollbar
- combobox
- listbox

`WndProc` is the sole driver of the behavior of the widget.

Hence the mapping: widget (control type) -> `wndclass` -> `WndProc`

Comment: Among other things, it's also used to specify some window attributes like the number of extra window memory available for [`GetWindowLongPtr()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633585.aspx). The number of extra window bytes a window uses is fixed once you create it.

Comment: Is there a historical reason to register the window class separately ?  Theoretically, the WndProc() can be passed as part of CreateWindow(). What is purpose of registration on windows system ?

Comment: There is some mechanism that will allow you to register windows classes globally, and use them in any application from that point in time.  In fact, every built-in windows control is registered that way.  I don't remember specifics, but you can look up 'global wndclass'